# How to create a class that stores pointers to member functions (C++)

Tags: c++, class, function-pointers

I'm trying to create a class that stores pointers to member functions of other classes and that can be executed from a text command (like a game console).

I did something functional, based on an example found here, that stores members with string-like input. Below is my implementation.

**file:** Command.hpp

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
    
using namespace std;

class Command
{
    public:
        Command();
        virtual ~Command();
        void RegisterCommand(string command, function<void(const string&)> fun);
        void Run(const string& command, const string& arg);

    private:
        unordered_map<string, function<void(const string&)>> functions;
};
```

**file:** Command.cpp

```
Command::Command()
{
}

Command::~Command()
{
}

void Command::RegisterCommand(string command, function<void(const string&)> fun)
{
    functions[command] = fun;
}

void Command::Run(const string& command, const string& arg)
{
    functions[command](arg);
}
```

**file:** main.cpp

```
#include "Command.hpp"

// function to register
void xyz_fun(const string& commandLine)
{
    cout << "console output: " << commandLine << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Command m_Cmd;

    // Register function
    m_Cmd.RegisterCommand("xyz_fun", xyz_fun);
    
    // Run registered function
    m_Cmd.Run("xyz_fun", "hello world.");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My question is how to implement a generic class to store members with unknown input arguments (Booleans, integers, doubles, strings, etc.).

For example, I could do:

```
m_Cmd.RegisterCommand("xyz_fun2", xyz_function2);
```

and call

```
m_Cmd.Run("xyz_fun2", false)
```

which has a boolean argument instead of a string.

Thanks in advance for your attention and any help is welcome.

Comment: What do you want to happen if `Run` is called with incorrect arguments?

Comment: *"a class that stores pointers to member functions"* -- this does not match your code. Your code uses function objects, not function pointers. (I suggest keeping the code and changing the question's text and title. Function objects look like a better fit for your goal.)

Comment: How do you decide which argument value to pass? For example, why `m_Cmd.Run("xyz_fun2", false)` instead of `m_Cmd.Run("xyz_fun2", true)`?

Comment: Hello, JaMiT. Thank you so much for your comments. Perhaps I have expressed myself poorly. My goal is to implement a class to handle commands passed by the user. They are simple commands, most of them with the sole purpose of changing some existing flags. For example: with the program running, the user can enter a command to change the window size. Or do this through a text file in an automated way (similar to a script).

Comment: Sorry for my confused question. I'm novice in c ++.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```cpp
        unordered_map<string, function<void(const string&)>> functions;
```

you could do

```cpp
        union acceptable_types { int i; char c; bool b; std::string* s; ... };
        unordered_map<string, function<void(acceptable_types)>> functions;
```

Then when calling functions, just place the value wanted by the function into a variable of type `acceptable_types`.
If a function is wants to use a specific value, it should just use a specific member of the `acceptable_types` union.
Here's an example:

```cpp
#include "Command.hpp"

void
my_bool_func (acceptable_types union_param)
{
        bool bool_var = union_param.b;
//      ...
//      Use bool_var
//      ...
}

void
my_string_func (acceptable_types union_param)
{
        std::string string_var = *(union_param.s);
//      ...
//      Use string_var
//      ...
}

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        Command my_command;
        acceptable_types union_var;

        my_command.RegisterCommand("my_bool_func", my_bool_func);
        my_command.RegisterCommand("my_string_func", my_string_func);

        union_var.b = true;
        my_command.Run("my_bool_func", union_var);

        *(union_var.s) = "hello world.";
        my_command.Run("my_string_func", union_var);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Neither `union` nor a raw pointer to an `std::string` are a good idea. The `union` is especially unsafe, particularly when there's no semblance of type-tracking/-checking as done here. You should recommend `std::variant` instead in such cases, as that has type-checking and value semantics.

Comment: Point proven: you already wrote/recommended undefined behaviour. Doing `*(union_var.s) = "hello world.";` here is nonsensical because you never allocated any `std::string` at that address, so you can't dereference it. You're using an invalid, uninitialised pointer, clobbering memory that isn't yours. And even if you did allocate it, you'd be advising newbies to write `new` and `delete` in C++, something that probably 99%+ of C++ coders should never need.